# magento 2: addErrorMessage() stripping html tags from message

Tags: magento2

I am trying to add the following error message for a custom integration:

```
"This email address is already associated with an account. 
Please log in <a href='https://1028-webtest.mpxhosting.com'>here</a>."
```

However `addErrorMessage()` strips tags, preventing the anchor to appear.  I can resolve this problem by using `addError()` but addError is deprecated and not the solution I am looking for.

Anyone know if there is another function or argument that can be used to define something like `strip_tags = false` when setting error messages?

v2.1.7

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I found something that might be helpful for anyone else who stumbles onto this problem.

There's something in Magento 2 called complex messages. And setting them up is... well complex.

First I needed to add to my modules etc/frontend/di.xml, I added this (change myexample and Vendor_Module to what you need)

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Message\MessageConfigurationsPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configurationsMap" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="myexample" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="renderer" xsi:type="const">\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Message\Renderer\BlockRenderer::CODE</item>
                    <item name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::messages/linked.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

Then my template file looked like this

```
<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($block->getData('pre_link_text'))?>
<a href="<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($block->getData('url'))?>"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__($block->getData('link_text'))) ?></a>
<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($block->getData('post_link_text'))?>
```

And in my Controller I added this to set the message:

```
$this->_messageManager->addComplexErrorMessage('myexample',
                [
                    'pre_link_text'=>'This is the text before the link',
                    'url' => 'https://example.com',
                    'link_text'=>'click here'
                ]);
```

Now run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` and maybe `php bin/magento cache:flush`

This site talks about it more depth: https://store.fooman.co.nz/blog/displaying-complex-error-messages-in-magento-2.html and this answer to another question is where my journey with complex messages started: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/267122/36655

Hope this helps someone.