# messageManager addSuccessMessage/addErrorMessage set cookies?

Tags: magento2, cookie, messages, notification, iphone

Whenever I `addSuccessMessage`/`addErrorMessage` it sets the cookie?
But I am not able to get that code, where that magic happens.

In `messages.js`
it gets that message by using code

```
$.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages');
```

In my case, once it set the cookieStorage it doesn't get clear even though I do it my code at the end of the script.

```
$.cookieStorage.set('mage-messages', '');
```

Comment: You have raised a good point. +1 for that

Answer (score 4):

I have also faced this similar issue and I got this resolved by implementing complex messages, like this:

Also you can include any custom html in any message also with this technique.

Implementing complex messages:

1. in modules di.xml:

   [image]
2. Trigger complex message insteed of simple message:

   $this->_messageManager->addComplexSuccessMessage('custom_rfq_success');
3. create .phtml containing message content: 
   at (/Namespace/Module/view/frontend/templates/messages/custom_rfq_success.phtml)

Just notice in the above of .phtml file having message content apply this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 require(['jquery','domReady!'], function($){
 setTimeout(function()
    {
        $.cookieStorage.set('mage-messages', '');
    }, 1000);
})
</script>
```

I was able to resolve that sticky message issue by this. Please check if it works well for you.

More information on complex messages:
https://store.fooman.co.nz/blog/displaying-complex-error-messages-in-magento-2.html

Thanks.

Comment: I need to put that each module di.xml? that's a pain

Comment: Can i write the message.phtml content in my custom_rfq_success.phtml, as i need same format, but message.phtml has data-bind and ko stuff (knockout)

Comment: Great solution, with above example an empty message box still shows as you have just a script in the message. I luckily needed a message however, would like to know a way to hide the message box if just wanna run a script?

Answer (score 0):

Success and error messages stores in customer data, you can always get and set customer data

```
require(['Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'], function(customerData){
    customerData.set('messages', {messages: ""});
});
```

This will empty data of messages in customer data.

Comment: then why in message.js message get and set from mage-messages cookie , in my case it shows all previous cookie messages even though I clear it using $cookieStorage('mage-messages',"") , for iPhone safari it's totally not working

Comment: Magento not just save messages in cookie, it also saves in local storage of your browser, check local storage and you will see, by using the method that I have mentioned, you will able to empty your local storage messages

Comment: In message.phtml also it gets data from cookieMessages  <div data-bind="foreach: { data: cookieMessages, as: 'message' }" class="messages">, which we get from cookieStorage , i dont see any role of customerData here

Comment: Check `removeAll` function in `messages.js` you will understand

Comment: look for `customerData` in entire `messages.js` it will surely clear stuff about `customerData`

Comment: @Shoaid Munir I don't see any mage-messages in browser local storage, can you tell me the key for this Magento stores messages in local storage in browser

Comment: messages is the key, where magento stores messages data, you will see it after add to cart any product, it will probably disappear instantly after showing message

Comment: What is customerData ? is it a map ?

Comment: it's a global variable where customer related data will store.

Comment: There are multiple messages.js file, which message.js file should i prefer, as you mentioned to check removeAll function in messages.js